# Saving Checkbox State

Tags: jquery

How do I save checkbox state using jquery? Do I need to use php session variables and pass that on to jQuery?

Comment: It depends on how you need it. one time? for a day? for a week?

Comment: Save the state why? For how long? Across multiple pages? Just long enough to show the form again but with error messages? Why do you want to involve jQuery in this in the first place? Is the form generating using JavaScript?

Comment: or a cookie or an xml file there are plenty of options available...

Comment: I'm using a jquery plugin for cookies. I also got the session going with localStorage. So... When a user comes to my site, they choose a layout option based on which checkbox the clicked and I need the browser to remember which checkbox they clicked.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you can do it Make use of Cookies...  You can create cookies by javascript and consume it easily.